# Holding derived class list objects in Base class list object

Tags: c#, oop, inheritance

How to hold Derived class list objects in Base class list object

```
class Base 
{
}

class Child : Base 
{
}

Base obj = new Child();
```

Will the same work for list.

```
List<Base> obj = new List<Child>();
```

This is giving me error, what is the best way to achive this.

Comment: Next line: `obj.Add(new SomeOtherClassInheritingFromBaseThatIsntChild())` - do you see the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Just because `Child` and `Base` have an implicit conversion, doesn't mean `List<Child>` and `List<Base>` do as these are now `List<>` objects.

```
List<Base> = (List<Base>)(new List<Child>())
```

You need to cast the child list to the parent list.

Comment: That cast won't work.

Comment: You're right. Would he have to define his own?